# jetpack compose :Theme color overrides not working in api 31 and above but working for api 30 and below

Tags: android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, material-design

i'm new to jetpack compose and i have been trying to override the background and surface colors in my app to see the effects, but it works only on my api 30 and below virtual devices but does nothing on my physical device which is api 31 and other virtual devices above api 30, i'm using material3

```
private val DarkColorScheme = darkColorScheme(
    primary = Purple80,
    secondary = PurpleGrey80,
    tertiary = Pink80,
    surface = Color(0XFF0C134F),
    background = Color(0XFF0C134F),
    onSurface = Color(0xffffffff)
)

private val LightColorScheme = lightColorScheme(
    primary = Purple40,
    secondary = PurpleGrey40,
    tertiary = Pink40,
    surface = Color(0XFFB6EAFA),
    background = Color(0XFFB6EAFA),

    /* Other default colors to override
    background = Color(0xFFFFFBFE),
    surface = Color(0xFFFFFBFE),
    onPrimary = Color.White,
    onSecondary = Color.White,
    onTertiary = Color.White,
    onBackground = Color(0xFF1C1B1F),
    onSurface = Color(0xFF1C1B1F),
    */
)

@Composable
fun JetweatherTheme(
    darkTheme: Boolean = isSystemInDarkTheme(),
    // Dynamic color is available on Android 12+
    dynamicColor: Boolean = true,
    content: @Composable () -> Unit
) {
    val colorScheme = when {
        dynamicColor  -> {
            val context = LocalContext.current
            if (darkTheme) dynamicDarkColorScheme(context) else dynamicLightColorScheme(context)
        }

        darkTheme -> DarkColorScheme
        else -> LightColorScheme
    }
    val view = LocalView.current
    if (!view.isInEditMode) {
        SideEffect {
            val window = (view.context as Activity).window
            window.statusBarColor = colorScheme.primary.toArgb()
            WindowCompat.getInsetsController(window, view).isAppearanceLightStatusBars = darkTheme
        }
    }

    MaterialTheme(
        colorScheme = colorScheme,
        typography = Typography,
        content = content
    )
}
```

and these are my dependencies

```
    def room_version = "2.5.1"

    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.8.0'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.3.1'
    implementation 'androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.5.1'
    implementation platform('androidx.compose:compose-bom:2022.10.00')
    implementation 'androidx.compose.ui:ui'
    implementation 'androidx.compose.ui:ui-graphics'
    implementation 'androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling-preview'
    implementation 'androidx.compose.material3:material3'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1'
    androidTestImplementation platform('androidx.compose:compose-bom:2022.10.00')
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-junit4'
    debugImplementation 'androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling'
    debugImplementation 'androidx.compose.ui:ui-test-manifest'
    //HILT
    implementation "com.google.dagger:hilt-android:2.44.2"
    kapt "com.google.dagger:hilt-compiler:2.45"
    kapt "androidx.hilt:hilt-compiler:1.0.0"
    implementation "androidx.hilt:hilt-navigation-compose:1.1.0-alpha01"

    //material icons - use with caution!
    // implementation "androidx.compose.material:material-icons-extended:$compose_version"
    // Coroutines
    implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.6.4'
    implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.6.4'
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-play-services:1.6.4"
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.4.0"

    // Retrofit
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.9.0'

    // OkHttp
    implementation("com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:5.0.0-alpha.2")

    // JSON Converter
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.9.0'

    //Room
    implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:$room_version"
    annotationProcessor "androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version"

    // To use Kotlin annotation processing tool (kapt) MUST HAVE!
    kapt("androidx.room:room-compiler:$room_version")
    implementation "androidx.room:room-ktx:$room_version"

    // Coil
    implementation("io.coil-kt:coil-compose:1.4.0")
```

i have tried updating all my dependencies, but that leads to a duplicate class error problem, when i update

```
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.8.0'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.3.1'
    implementation 'androidx.activity:activity-compose:1.5.1'
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.4.0"
```

to their latest versions

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Android introduced [Material You](https://source.android.com/docs/core/display/material) from API level 31 and above which acquires theme colors from the wallpaper.

You can turn this feature off by setting the `dynamicColor` to `false`:

```kotlin
@Composable
fun JetweatherTheme(
    darkTheme: Boolean = isSystemInDarkTheme(),
    // Dynamic color is available on Android 12+
    dynamicColor: Boolean = false, 
    content: @Composable () -> Unit
)
```

Comment: Thank you very much, so it was the using dynamicDarkColorScheme instead of dark ColorScheme